# Contour integration of: $\int_C \frac{2}{z^2-1}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to calculate this (**for a homework problem, so understanding is the goal**)
$$\int_C \frac{2}{z^2-1}\,dz$$ where $C$ is the circle of radius $\frac12$ centre $1$, positively oriented.

---

My thoughts:

$$z=-1+\frac12e^{i\theta},\,0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$$

$$z'=\frac{i}{2}e^{i\theta},f(z) = \frac{}{}$$, from here it is going to get really messy, so I doubt that is the direction I should go. Where *should* I go?

Or is it meant to get messy from here on out?

Comment: Use the Cauchy Integral Theorem.

Comment: It is one of the Cauchy formula

Comment: @skiesburn While the residue theorem is the more efficient way to proceed, one can instead use a direct method here.  And this was the approach I took.  So, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only singularity of the function $f(z)=\frac{2}{z^2-1}$ on the domain $|z-1|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ is the simple pole in $z=1$, by the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) we have:
$$\oint_{|z-1|=\frac{1}{2}}f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=1\right)=2\pi i\cdot\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{2}{z+1}=\color{red}{2\pi i}. $$

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how you have calculated this 'residue'. Where did it come from? I can't see what was subbed into $f(z)$

Comment: @SkiesBurn: if $z_0$ is a simple pole for $f(z)$, the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=z_0$ is simply given by $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)\,f(z)$.

Comment: So essentially I have $(z-1)^m$ where $m=1$ and since $m=1$ this is a simple pole and we can use that expression from the above comment

Comment: @SkiesBurn: we can use the above expression since $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}$$ gives that $f$ has a simple pole over our domain. Simple pole in $z=z_0$ means that $f(z)$ has a singularity in $z=z_0$ but $(z-z_0)f(z)$ is a holomorphic function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [residue theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to find integrals of this type. And observe that the only singular point for this analytic function in the disk above is at $z=1$.

Comment: From a quick scan(before a full read) it looks like I will prefer the form $|z-1|=\frac12$, is this a better choice before I start learning this?

Comment: This type of integrals are better to solve with the above theorem, but for learning and knowing that it's really useful you can calculate the integral by elementary methods and will be better to find the above theorem a gem in complex analysis...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to proceed is to use the residue theorem.  Since so many respondents have already tackled the problem along that line, we will proceed here directly and evaluate the contour integral using brute force.

We will use the parameterization $z=1+\frac12 e^{it}$, $0\le t< 2\pi$.  Then $dz = ie^{it}dt$.  To that end, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{2}{z^2-1}dz&=\oint_C \left(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right) dz\tag1\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{1}{(1+\frac12 e^{it})-1}-\frac{1}{(1+\frac12 e^{it})+1}\right)\frac12ie^{it}dt\tag 2\\\\
&=2\pi i-\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{4+ e^{it}}dt\tag3\\\\
&=2\pi i-\log(4+e^{it})|_0^{2\pi}\tag4\\\\
&=2\pi i\tag5
\end{align}$$

For (1), we used partial fraction expansion of the integrand.

For (2), we used the aforementioned parameterization.

For (3), we evaluated the first integral as $\int_0^{2\pi} i dt=2\pi i.

For (4), we observed that the anti-derivative of the integrand was $\log (4+e^{it})$.

For (5), we evaluated that anti-derivative between the limits, and noted that $e^{i2\pi}=e^{i0}=1$ and so the integral is zero.